Dirty VS clean ground: How to tie grounds?
I am trying to understand when grounds can be connected together and when they should not be. So far, I have learned the following:

Clean grounds should be connected together, as should dirty grounds.
The connection between noisy and clean grounds should be tied at only one point, through a capacitor.

I have a PCB design featuring two identical buck converters. Please refer to the illustration below:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This image serves as a framework for my thought process. I have labeled the grounds based on my understanding. The 24V input ground is considered dirty. After the inductor, it undergoes filtration, making the second ground cleaner. The ground associated with the switch appears even dirtier to me than the ground connected to C1/C3, while the ground for C2 and C4 seems clean.
Based on the principles mentioned above, it seems that I can connect DIRTY GROUND 1 to DIRTY GROUND 2, CLEANER GROUND 1 to CLEANER GROUND 2, NOISY GROUND_DIRTY1 to NOISY GROUND_DIRTY2, and CLEAN GROUND 1 to CLEAN GROUND 2.
None of these grounds should be connected to each other. Is my understanding correct?

What you have learned is not correct.  You almost always need to connect grounds together directly.  If you try to connect them with only a capacitor, then no DC circuit exists, which is almost certainly not what you want if you are connecting them at all.

Noise on ground is really just current times an impedance, so rather than filtering it usually one tries to manage where current travels while keeping impedances low.  How you do that will depend greatly on frequency, but for high frequency devices like buck converters, usually a solid ground plane and careful routing of traces to avoid return currents is a good solution.  At lower frequencies where current spreads out more, things like star grounding may be required.  But the solution depends on the problem, so what are you really designing?

What they said! but also. having only one ground also makes everything much easier

@user1850479 Thank you. I made a significant mistake in my understanding, and I'm not sure where I picked it up. However, you are definitely correct. Upon reviewing many designs from my company, I've noticed that they have indeed used 0-ohm resistors to connect what is referred to as noisy and clean grounds.

If I provide a low-impedance return plane for all my forward traces, I can connect all these low-impedance return planes together and create a large ground plane. If this understanding is correct, why do I see many divided/separated ground copper planes on PCBs?

Dividing up ground planes may be helpful at very low frequency where current spreads out. Cuts in the plane can control where it flows, at least if done very carefully. At higher frequency this is usually not very helpful since return current stays under traces anyway. What you see may be a reflection of the types of boards you are looking at. Or bad design. The answers here might give some insight: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/659033/how-to-design-a-schematic-and-pcb-for-an-adc-using-separated-grounds/659078

To expand on the comment from @user1850479:
"Noisy ground" arises when you have a lot of current flowing in the ground node, or when the impedance of the ground node is high, or both.
For low frequency currents, this is easy to understand: The impedance is the resistance of the ground node. In order to keep this low for use with high currents, one can either use a thicker ground plane, or one can make dedicated traces for each of the larger currents, so at least the large currents don't offset the ground potential of other signals. The latter technique emphasizes on a very important aspect: It turns the current supply into a local pair of forward and return current wires, which can be laid out in parallel to keep it tidy and to keep its loop area small.
For higher frequency, the notion of a "ground node" becomes more and more questionable anyway, because this (usually large) node will not be at the same potential everywhere. Even if you have an extended ground node, current can and will flow in separate regions of it. There is no longer a need to form dedicated trace pairs, but it is necessary (and sufficient) to keep the forward trace in tight vicinity of the return current node, e.g. a trace over a ground plane. The return currents will stay local automatically and no "dirty ground" will be formed.
So to summarize, it is almost always best to form a large continuous ground node or plane, because this keeps low frequency resistance down and higher frequency currents easily find a return current path close to their forward trace. Only for large low frequency currents should you consider to run a dedicated return current trace. "Large currents" is subjective here of course: if precision is important, almost every current is large and should be passed around differentially with dedicated return current traces.

thank you. So, it seems my understanding was completely off. If we ensure a low-impedance ground path, they will indeed be connected together, correct? Does this mean we need not worry about where to connect them? So, if I place a ground plane under these components, would that resolve the issue?

@chami probably yes, but good placing of components on the ground plane helps a lot in keeping all currents local. This is also a general concept unless your goal is to create large mag fields: Keep current loops small and local

I believe this is where I've always been confused. If I provide a low-impedance return plane for all my forward traces, I can connect all these low-impedance return planes together and create a large ground plane. If this understanding is correct, why do discussions about keeping grounds local arise? Additionally, why do I observe many designs where all grounds are not connected together whenever there's an opportunity to do so? Why do I see many divided/separated ground copper planes on PCBs? Thank you.

@chami In the past, as little as maybe until 10 yrs ago, splitting grounds into local noninteracting sections has been often recommended. But this suggestion was built on premises which couldn't be fulfilled in practice, such as star grounding where there is only ever one path through ground to a destination. The fundamental theme nowadays is: keep current loops small and/or local. This implies to abandon the star grounding, it solves many many issues but it introduces a few pitfalls, namely: ...

@chami ... namely that you cannot have low frequency large currents through the ground node and simultaneously use the ground as a reference for precision single-ended signals. With star grounding, the star point has an absolutely stable and reliable potential. But this shortcoming is easy to fix: Just use dedicated ground return traces for both low frequency currents and precision signals. This is much easier than fixing the star ground approach

Assuming standard 24V or lower voltage electronics, then the general rule for systems in "dirty" environments with lots of EMI is to connect all grounds together, directly. And eventually to chassis, at some point. This is also the standard counter-measure against ESD.
We just need to be sensible about where we connect them. We don't want conducted EMI to enter the PCB ground. Nor do we want unexpected ground currents to happen if we manage to create a better path for such currents, like for example connecting both sides of a cable shield to chassis at some unfortunate place.
As mentioned in comments, you can't connect the PCB ground through a series capacitor since that would block DC currents and then if that's the only point of ground, then no DC current can pass through your PCB at all... meaning it will stay dead in most situations.
Common practice is to connect the PCB ground to the supply ground where it enters your system/product. Then all currents flowing through your system will leave through that supply ground and there are no currents going the other direction, since all currents are always heading for the mains ground/battery cathode etc - they won't take any detours through your PCB ground unless you give them reason to, like providing a lower resistance path to - than they would otherwise take.
Similarly, the PCB ground should not be connected to chassis anywhere else but close to the supply ground pin, so no dirty ground currents will decide to take the route through your PCB.
In case you worry about spikes and surges from the ground, a bidirectional TVS could be placed on the supply input to your system, as well as a large "bulk" capacitor.
And you should be using the same philosophy inside your system/PCB too: the buck regulators will have high currents and generate noise, so they need their own dedicated ground which should be connected to the larger PCB ground at the point where the supply enters the board. Regulator design is a big topic of its own.

Thank you. Could you elaborate further? If we intend to connect these grounds together and ensure that all forward traces have a low impedance return pass, why should we concern ourselves with "where" they are connected?
